# Order dates with multiple columns (some containing nulls)

Tags: t-sql, date, sql-order-by

I have 4 dates (derived from separate subqueries) as in below but I want to find the MAX and MIN dates of the values returned. 
I've tried using CASE which will not work with the null values.
Also tried using COALESCE in the subs to get values and then using CTE but this also didn't work.

(The overall query is to find customers with no -9 in a1.id)

There's a lot of help in SO but nothing that I can get to fit this purpose.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
                                                          DESIRED COLUMNS
PAT_ID   Date1       Date2       Date3       Date4        MAX         MIN
   1     01/04/2015  25/12/2000  02/02/2011               01/04/2015  25/12/2000
   2                 05/08/1950  11/11/2011               11/11/2011  05/08/1950
   3                                         04/01/1958   04/01/1958  04/01/1958
   4                                                      01/01/1900  01/01/1900
   5     15/08/2017              07/07/1967               15/08/2017  07/07/1967

```
select distinct 
ca1.id AS PT_ID,

(select Top 1 s1z.appointmen ApptDate
from schl_booking_appoin s1z
LEFT OUTER JOIN core_patient c3z ON s1z.patient = c3z.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN schl_appt_history_s s2z ON s1z.currentsta = s2z.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN applookup_instance a2z ON s2z.lkp_status = a2z.id
where (c3z.id = ca1.id and a2z.text not like '%cancelled%' and s1z.appointmen 
> :SYS_DATE_TIME) 
order by s1z.appointmen asc ) AS Date1,

(select Top 1 
s1q.appointmen ApptDate
from schl_booking_appoin s1q 
LEFT OUTER JOIN core_patient c3q ON s1q.patient = c3q.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN schl_appt_history_s s2q ON s1q.currentsta = s2q.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN applookup_instance a2q ON s2q.lkp_status = a2q.id
where (c3q.id = ca1.id and a2q.text not like '%cancelled%' and s1q.appointmen         
< :SYS_DATE_TIME) 
order by s1q.appointmen desc ) AS Date2,

(select top 1
CONVERT (VARCHAR(20),c2y.admissiond, 103) AdmissionDate
from core_admissiondetai c2y 
LEFT OUTER JOIN core_pas_event c3y ON c2y.pasevent = c3y.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN core_patient c4y ON c3y.patient = c4y.id
where (c4y.id = ca1.id) 
order by c2y.admissiond desc ) AS Date3,

(select top 1 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),c5k.arrivaldat,103) ArrivalDate
from core_emergencyatten c5k 
LEFT OUTER JOIN core_patient c6k ON c5k.patient = c6k.id
where (c6k.id = ca1.id) 
order by c5k.arrivaldat desc ) AS Date4

from core_patient ca1
LEFT OUTER JOIN core_patient_c_identifi ca2 ON ca1.id = ca2.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN applookup_instance aa2 ON ca1.lkp_sex = aa2.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN applookup_instance aa1 ON ca2.lkp_c_ty = aa1.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN applookup_instance ab1 ON ca1.lkp_overseascl = ab1.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN core_organisation cx4 ON ca1.practice = cx4.id

WHERE ca1.id IN 
(
select c1.id core_patient_c1_id 
from core_patient c1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN core_patient_c_identifi c2 ON c1.id = c2.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN applookup_instance a1 ON c2.lkp_c_ty = a1.id
where ((ca2.merged = 0 or ca2.merged is null) 
and aa1.id = -2404) )


AND ca1.id NOT IN (
select c1.id core_patient_c1_id 
from core_patient c1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN core_patient_c_identifi c2 ON c1.id = c2.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN applookup_instance a1 ON c2.lkp_c_ty = a1.id
where (c1.namesurname not like '%XXTEST%' 
and c1.namesurname not like '%ZZ%' 
and a1.id = -9)
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this version. Your old query acts as a subquery and introducing a new column definition to get the Max Date.

```
SELECT PT_ID, 
 (
      SELECT Max(v) 
       FROM (VALUES (Date1), (Date2), (Date3),(Date4)) AS value(v) 
   ) as [MaxDate]

FROM
(
select distinct 
ca1.id AS PT_ID,

(select Top 1 s1z.appointmen ApptDate
from schl_booking_appoin s1z
LEFT OUTER JOIN core_patient c3z ON s1z.patient = c3z.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN schl_appt_history_s s2z ON s1z.currentsta = s2z.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN applookup_instance a2z ON s2z.lkp_status = a2z.id
where (c3z.id = ca1.id and a2z.text not like '%cancelled%' and s1z.appointmen 
> :SYS_DATE_TIME) 
order by s1z.appointmen asc ) AS Date1,

(select Top 1 
s1q.appointmen ApptDate
from schl_booking_appoin s1q 
LEFT OUTER JOIN core_patient c3q ON s1q.patient = c3q.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN schl_appt_history_s s2q ON s1q.currentsta = s2q.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN applookup_instance a2q ON s2q.lkp_status = a2q.id
where (c3q.id = ca1.id and a2q.text not like '%cancelled%' and s1q.appointmen         
< :SYS_DATE_TIME) 
order by s1q.appointmen desc ) AS Date2,

(select top 1
CONVERT (VARCHAR(20),c2y.admissiond, 103) AdmissionDate
from core_admissiondetai c2y 
LEFT OUTER JOIN core_pas_event c3y ON c2y.pasevent = c3y.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN core_patient c4y ON c3y.patient = c4y.id
where (c4y.id = ca1.id) 
order by c2y.admissiond desc ) AS Date3,

(select top 1 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),c5k.arrivaldat,103) ArrivalDate
from core_emergencyatten c5k 
LEFT OUTER JOIN core_patient c6k ON c5k.patient = c6k.id
where (c6k.id = ca1.id) 
order by c5k.arrivaldat desc ) AS Date4

from core_patient ca1
LEFT OUTER JOIN core_patient_c_identifi ca2 ON ca1.id = ca2.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN applookup_instance aa2 ON ca1.lkp_sex = aa2.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN applookup_instance aa1 ON ca2.lkp_c_ty = aa1.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN applookup_instance ab1 ON ca1.lkp_overseascl = ab1.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN core_organisation cx4 ON ca1.practice = cx4.id

WHERE ca1.id IN 
(
select c1.id core_patient_c1_id 
from core_patient c1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN core_patient_c_identifi c2 ON c1.id = c2.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN applookup_instance a1 ON c2.lkp_c_ty = a1.id
where ((ca2.merged = 0 or ca2.merged is null) 
and aa1.id = -2404) )


AND ca1.id NOT IN (
select c1.id core_patient_c1_id 
from core_patient c1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN core_patient_c_identifi c2 ON c1.id = c2.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN applookup_instance a1 ON c2.lkp_c_ty = a1.id
where (c1.namesurname not like '%XXTEST%' 
and c1.namesurname not like '%ZZ%' 
and a1.id = -9)
)

)Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for this, it's just the ticket! I've never thought of using it like this and I've tried multiple ways each resulting in different problems. Would there be any way to exclude results if they returned null?

Comment: Hi Scotty, I am assuming that you mean where all the four dates are null. Then you can just add in the where clause : "WHERE 
 COALESCE(Date1,Date2,Date3,Date4) IS NOT NULL"

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

- make your query into a CTE;
- flatten the data so it becomes a list of PT_IDs and dates;
- from this flattened data find the maximum and minimum date per PT_ID;
- bring this all back together in one final query.

This is a stab at doing all of the above:

```
WITH x AS (
    select distinct 
    ca1.id AS PT_ID,

    (select Top 1 s1z.appointmen ApptDate
    from schl_booking_appoin s1z
    LEFT OUTER JOIN core_patient c3z ON s1z.patient = c3z.id 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN schl_appt_history_s s2z ON s1z.currentsta = s2z.id 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN applookup_instance a2z ON s2z.lkp_status = a2z.id
    where (c3z.id = ca1.id and a2z.text not like '%cancelled%' and s1z.appointmen 
    > :SYS_DATE_TIME) 
    order by s1z.appointmen asc ) AS Date1,

    (select Top 1 
    s1q.appointmen ApptDate
    from schl_booking_appoin s1q 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN core_patient c3q ON s1q.patient = c3q.id 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN schl_appt_history_s s2q ON s1q.currentsta = s2q.id 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN applookup_instance a2q ON s2q.lkp_status = a2q.id
    where (c3q.id = ca1.id and a2q.text not like '%cancelled%' and s1q.appointmen         
    < :SYS_DATE_TIME) 
    order by s1q.appointmen desc ) AS Date2,

    (select top 1
    CONVERT (VARCHAR(20),c2y.admissiond, 103) AdmissionDate
    from core_admissiondetai c2y 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN core_pas_event c3y ON c2y.pasevent = c3y.id 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN core_patient c4y ON c3y.patient = c4y.id
    where (c4y.id = ca1.id) 
    order by c2y.admissiond desc ) AS Date3,

    (select top 1 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),c5k.arrivaldat,103) ArrivalDate
    from core_emergencyatten c5k 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN core_patient c6k ON c5k.patient = c6k.id
    where (c6k.id = ca1.id) 
    order by c5k.arrivaldat desc ) AS Date4

    from core_patient ca1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN core_patient_c_identifi ca2 ON ca1.id = ca2.id 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN applookup_instance aa2 ON ca1.lkp_sex = aa2.id 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN applookup_instance aa1 ON ca2.lkp_c_ty = aa1.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN applookup_instance ab1 ON ca1.lkp_overseascl = ab1.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN core_organisation cx4 ON ca1.practice = cx4.id

    WHERE ca1.id IN 
    (
    select c1.id core_patient_c1_id 
    from core_patient c1 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN core_patient_c_identifi c2 ON c1.id = c2.id 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN applookup_instance a1 ON c2.lkp_c_ty = a1.id
    where ((ca2.merged = 0 or ca2.merged is null) 
    and aa1.id = -2404) )


    AND ca1.id NOT IN (
    select c1.id core_patient_c1_id 
    from core_patient c1 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN core_patient_c_identifi c2 ON c1.id = c2.id 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN applookup_instance a1 ON c2.lkp_c_ty = a1.id
    where (c1.namesurname not like '%XXTEST%' 
    and c1.namesurname not like '%ZZ%' 
    and a1.id = -9)
    )),
y AS (
    SELECT PT_ID, Date1 AS [Date] FROM x WHERE Date1 IS NOT NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT PT_ID, Date2 AS [Date] FROM x WHERE Date2 IS NOT NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT PT_ID, Date3 AS [Date] FROM x WHERE Date3 IS NOT NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT PT_ID, Date4 AS [Date] FROM x WHERE Date4 IS NOT NULL),
z AS (
    SELECT
        PT_ID,
        MIN([Date]) AS Min_Date,
        MAX([Date]) AS Max_Date
    FROM
        y
    GROUP BY
        PT_ID)
SELECT
    x.PT_ID,
    x.Date1,
    x.Date2,
    x.Date3,
    x.Date4,
    z.Min_Date,
    z.Max_Date
FROM
    x
    LEFT JOIN z ON z.PT_ID = x.PT_ID;
```